# How to create button that will create an object?

Tags: java, javafx

Hello I'm  little bit new to Java.

I have a public class Instance

```
String name;
String number;

public Instance(String instanceName, String instanceNumber){
    name=instanceName;
    number=instanceNumber;
}
```

and class Myclass that includes some values. There are textfields nitext and ni1text and button nibutton which I want to use to create new Instance objects

```
    Button nibutton = new Button("Add");
    nibutton.setOnAction((ae)->
        Instance nitext.getText()=new Instance(nitext.getText(), ni1text.getText())
        );
```

and it's not working. Manually, using Instance blabla = new Instance [...] everything works fine.

How it should looks like?
THX for help

edit:

OK I've added action listener;

```
    nibutton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        Instance nitext.getText()=new Instance(nitext.getText(), nc1text.getText();)
    }
    });
```

but got 3 "illegal start of expression" errors with ^ showing ".", ";" and ")"

Comment: You cannot have dynamic variable names in Java. You need to name them while writing the source code. Replace `nitext.getText()` with a proper variable name like `instance` or something similar.

Comment: unfortunatelly not working :/

Comment: changed nitext.getText() to some string, still nothing

Comment: Something like this - `Instance instance = new Instance(nitext.getText(), nc1text.getText());` ?

Comment: Yes. It wasn't working without action event handler. Problem solved, I've added new comment :) 
THX for help

Answer (score 0):

Create anoymous inner `ActionListener` class object:

```
    button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // create whatever you want
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain more? like I said, I'm new to java,
what should I create in place "whatever you want"?

pozdrawiam ;P

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

```
    Button nibutton = new Button("Add");
    nibutton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
            Instance anything = new Instance(ni1text.getText(), nc2text.getText());
        }
    });
```

Only problem is that we can't create dynamic object name (so can't use nitext.getText() instead of "anything" in this case).

THX for any help!